# product setPrice() not updating value for "default values" in store view

Tags: magento-1.9, products

I have three store view in my magento site. I want to update product price programmatically for all store view.

For this I am using below code :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(1)->load($id);
$product->setPrice(ceil($product_price))->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'price');
```

And similar to other store, This is working and updated price respectively to all store view.

But `default values` showing price `0.00` in magento admin grid.
Why below code is not working?

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$product->setPrice(ceil($product_price))->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'price');
```

How to do that?

Comment: Check you whether you are updating price for configurable product id.

Comment: My product is `Virtual` type.

Comment: Set break points to check the correct product is loading and also the `$product_price` in the program. Your syntax is seems to valid.

Comment: Yes I checked, 'product_id' is same  and my code/syntax is valid. product price for all three store view updated by my code and on frontend product  showing correct price on all store but default value showing in admin is 0.00 still.

Comment: It is working now after adding `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);` in my file.

Comment: Congrats... Glad to hear that.

Comment: You can add this in answer. May be it help to some one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to add admin permission if we try to save default values for product from any external file as below :

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STOR‌​E_ID);
```

It also remove any integrity violation.